# CSP: What is script-src-attr and script-src-elem?

Tags: xss, javascript, content-security-policy, header

script-src-attr and script-src-elem directives are new additions in CSP3.
I am not able to understand how are they different from the script-src directive.

https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-script-src-elem

This documents the new addition but I am not able to clearly differentiate between the usage, maybe due to hard language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script-src-elem works on script tags:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
<script src="/jquery.js">
```

Script-src-attr works on attributes that contain JavaScript:

```
<svg onload="alert(1)">
```

More information can be found in the  [Intent to Implement and Ship: CSP3: `script-src-attr`, `script-src-elem`, `style-src-attr`, `style-src-elem` directives](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/uauMQQQ7fAI)

Comment: Will the reports generated by the violation of script-src directive be replaced by script-src-elem then?